# ¿Cómo imprimir valor del post con un salto de linea?

Tags: php, html5

Deseo imprimir el valor de un `post` pero si este valor pasa a la siguiente linea, que tenga un saldo de `<br>` imprimiendo el resto del `post`. Por ejemplo estoy haciendo un reporte `PDF` pero al imprimir por ejemplo el valor del `post` objetivo que es largo. Puede darme alguno dar una idea de como llevarlo a cabo.

[image: codigo]
[image: pdf generado]

Comment: puedes mostrar el codigo que estas usando para mostrar la salida, que tipo de salida es y como se ve este pdf???

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez agregue las imagenes para que tengas una idea de lo que necesito ayuda, gracias de antemano amigo

Answer (score 0):

Podrías contar los caracteres y si es mayor a un número que haga pasar el POST a la siguiente linea imprimir un salto de linea. Aproximadamente conté 24 caracteres, tendrás que ir probando:

```
<?= strlen($_POST["proyecto"]) > 24 ? "<br>" : ""; ?>
```

y luego imprimir tu valor

```
<strong><?= $_POST["proyecto"]; ?></strong>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comenario, y viendo tu logica tienes razon, pero por al parecer no me funciona, como bien dices igual conté 24 caracteres eso contando este ejemplo, mando a imprimir como me describes y pues el operador ternario esta bien

Comment: @IvanHernandez podrías poner cómo usaste el código según el ejemplo que te di para entender mejor?

Answer (score 0):

Dado que estas usando `html` y solo es visualizar el texto como muestras, podrías usar `css`.

Ejemplo:

```
....documento recepcional denominado <br>
<strong style="white-space:normal;"><?=" ".$_POST['proyecto']." " ?></strong>
```

el `style` es solo para ejemplo mejor usa una clase o id.

Comment: Mi amigo la imagen ya sale asi como la ilustro, lo que quiero es que la informacion cargada del post se visualize como las demas informacion que tenga un saldo de linea y no que salgan juntas, ACERCÁNDONOS AL FUTURO A TRAVÉS DEL LIBRO DIGITAL: NUEVO MANUAL DE ESTUDIO PARA LA ASIGNATURA IDIOMA ESPAÑOL DESTINADO A ALUMNOS DE PRIMER AÑO DE C.B DE SECUNDARIA

Answer (score 0):

[image: code]
@Camilo Fernández asi es como estoy usando tu linea que me dijiste que podria usar